# ¿Como habilitar el keylistener de un panel en un JFrame?

Tags: java, java-swing

Una consulta, tengo 2 clases que extienden del JPanel, una es para agregar mis botones y demas, y la otra que es el panel de juego, esta clase de panelJuego implementa el keyListiner, ahora mi pregunta es, como puedo habilitar mi keylistener en mi clase ventana que extiende el JFrame en donde estan contenidos mi panel de botones y mi panel de juego.

Adjunto el codigo, que tendran un buen dia!!!!!!!!!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Ventana extends JFrame {
    private PanelJuego panelJuego = new PanelJuego();
    private PanelMenu menuPanel = new PanelMenu(panelJuego);

    public Ventana(){
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500,500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        anadirComponente();
        
    }

    public void anadirComponente(){

        menuPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        panelJuego.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.getContentPane().add(menuPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.getContentPane().add(panelJuego, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: ya intentaste con [key adapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyAdapter.html)?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus comentarios... por el momento pude arreglar mi problema con un "requestFocus();" al momento de dar click en el boton reiniciar.

Answer (score 0):

Por motivos mas didácticos, adjunto en código completo para la comunidad, y explico como creo yo logre solucionarlo, al momento de crear el panel menú, le pase en el constructor el panel de juego y la ventana para que al momento de reiniciar a la posición del jugador (Click en reiniciar) se le asigne la posición de inicio y a la ventana se le ejecute la función de "requestFocus();", si alguien pudiera explicar un poco como funciona esta función se lo agradecería, ya que en muchas ocasiones resulta muy técnica su definición.

Que tengan un excelente buen día!!!

**Clase Ventana

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Ventana extends JFrame {
    private PanelJuego panelJuego ;
    private PanelMenu menuPanel;

    public Ventana(){

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500,500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        anadirComponente();

    }

    public void anadirComponente(){

        panelJuego = new PanelJuego();
        menuPanel = new PanelMenu(panelJuego, this);

        menuPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        panelJuego.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.getContentPane().add(menuPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.getContentPane().add(panelJuego, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.addKeyListener(panelJuego);
        this.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

**Clase Panel Menu

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class PanelMenu extends JPanel {

    private JButton reiniciar = new JButton("Reiniciar");
    private Ventana ventana;
    private JTextField txtPuntos = new JTextField("0");
    private JButton salir = new JButton("Salir");

    private PanelJuego panel;

    public PanelMenu(PanelJuego panel, Ventana ventana) {
        setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        this.ventana = ventana;
        this.panel = panel;
        reiniciar.addActionListener(e -> {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Juego reiniciado");
            panel.reiniciar();
            ventana.requestFocus();
        });
        add(reiniciar);
    }

    public void actualizarPuntos(int puntos){
        txtPuntos.setText(String.valueOf(puntos));
    }

    public void borrarPuntos(){
        txtPuntos.setText("0");
    }

    public void borrarCampo(){
        txtPuntos.setText("");
    }

}
```

** Clase Panel Juego

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class PanelJuego extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

    private jugadorCuadrado jugador = new jugadorCuadrado(100,100);

    public PanelJuego(){
        setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        setVisible(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillRect(jugador.getPosX(), jugador.getPosY(), 20,20);
        g.setColor(Color.magenta);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            jugador.setPosY(jugador.getPosY()+2);
            this.repaint();
            System.out.println("Abajo");
        }

        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            jugador.setPosY(jugador.getPosY()-2);
            this.repaint();
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            jugador.setPosX(jugador.getPosX()-2);
            this.repaint();
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            jugador.setPosX(jugador.getPosX()+2);
            this.repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_H){
            System.out.println("Hola");
        }
    }

    public void reiniciar(){
        jugador.setPosX(100);
        jugador.setPosY(100);
        this.repaint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Ventana extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

private PanelJuego panelJuego = new PanelJuego();
private PanelMenu menuPanel = new PanelMenu(panelJuego);

// Desde aquí no puedes crear un objeto oyente. Las órdenes solo se ejecutan dentro del constructor o desde un 
// método que sea llamado por el constructor.

public Ventana(){
    
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(500,500);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    anadirComponente();

    componente.addActionListener(this);
    
}

public void anadirComponente(){

    menuPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    panelJuego.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.getContentPane().add(menuPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.getContentPane().add(panelJuego, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    // ÓRDENES A EJECUTAR.


}
}
```

Espero haberle ayudado pero hubiera podido más si me hubiera indicado el componente al que se le asocia el objeto oyente. Un saludo.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow en español! Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).